# impossible to start sphinx search : error 1067

Tags: windows-services, sphinx

I'm working in Windows, I want to start sphinx search service. I tried firts to start by command line then  in the list of Services panel but I have this error

> windows could not start SphinxSearch service on local computer Error:
>   1067 The process terminated unexpectedly.

I've searched and tried solution in another post i ve found and nothing work

this is my config files C:\Sphinx\bin\sphinx.conf

```
searchd
{
        listen= 127.0.0.1:9306:mysql41
        log       = C:\Sphinx\log\searchd.log
        query_log = C:\Sphinx\log\query.log
    pid_file  = C:\Sphinx\log\searchd.pid

}
index news 
{
    source = news 
    path =C:\Sphinx\data\news
}
indexer
{
    mem_limit = 32M
}

source news
{
        type                = mysql
        sql_host            = localhost
        sql_user            = root
        sql_pass            = 
        sql_db              = newssdz
    sql_query_pre       = SET NAMES utf8
        sql_query           = SELECT id\
                                    , categorie\
                                    , titre\
                                    , contenu FROM news
    sql_attr_uint       = categorie
        sql_query_info      = SELECT titre FROM news WHERE id=$id

}
```

My error log files is empty so i can't find what is wrong. 
I have already change my write permission for all folder.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried just starting searchd directly? - not as a service, just on the command line.

Comment: I reinstall sphinx,I move on Windows 8, before i use windows XP and  download another version of sphinx search and  sphinx service work, but now  when I do command "search" it say  "not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file", did I missed something?

Comment: the 'search' binary is no longer provided. its been removed.

Comment: What we use instead for testing, thanks in advance

Comment: Can use test.php (in the api/ folder) - its a better test as it actully uses searchd.